# Two or more verbs modifying a noun

Tags: grammar, verbs, て-form

I would like to know about how we deal with two or more verbs modifying a noun. Do we connect the verbs using the TE-form or do we keep them in their original tenses?

> 激しい雷を**伴った**昨日から**降り続いている**雨のせいで、電車が遅れている。(Found this sentence on a native site - https://webdirectorsguide.com/blog/know-how/basic-knowledge/2015/02/061318)

In this case it seems that the correct choice would be to use the original tenses of the verbs.

But, I've also thought up sentences like:

> **買って**読んだ本がつまらない。

I don't know if using the te-form is correct but it seems to make sense.

Are both forms of using two or more verbs to describe a noun correct? If so, the cases where we have to use one or the other are different?

Comment: Please link your source (https://webdirectorsguide.com/blog/know-how/basic-knowledge/2015/02/061318) ??

Comment: also in your first example, did you not notice that the three verbs in  the sentence are referencing different nouns?

Comment: According to the source, the idea is that both 伴った and 昨日から降り続いている are separate elements that modify 雨.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the て form, order is implied. In your example, you bought the book then read it, so the て is appropriate.

In the example sentence you gave, the accompanying thunder (雷を伴った）isn't happening before 降り続いている since there's no て

> Because of the rain, which brought thunder and has been continuing since yesterday, the train is (currently) late

So to answer your question, if the sequence of events matters, the て form is correct. Otherwise, you don't need to use the てform to connect two verbs

---

Though you didn't ask about this in your question, the first sentence you posted actually isn't a very clear sentence because it's not clear whether 激しい is modifying 雨 or 雷. Instead, the article recommends the following 2 revisions:

> 昨日から降りつづいている、雷を伴った激しい雨のせいで、電車が遅れている。
>
> 昨日から、雷を伴った激しい雨が降り続いている。そのせいで、電車が遅れている。